# How to add an empty line between paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, lyx

I have two sections which I'd like to separate by an empty line. Every time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, LyX removes that empty line between paragraphs. How do I prevent this?

Comment: I had been having the same problem over and over again and also discovered from this post that `\bigbreak` worked and then I included a `\noindent` to create nicely formatted paragraphs, rather than using `\begin{sloppypar}` and `\end{sloppypar}` which was pointless.

Answer (score 175):

This is LyX's way of staying true to LaTeX where successive blank lines are merged - a good thing when you're talking about consistent document layout/design. If you wish to insert a forced vertical skip, insert an ERT containing either `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip` or a fixed `\vspace{<len>}` where you specify [`<len>`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4239/5764). For a fixed/hard, single blank line, use `\vspace{\baselineskip}` (roughly the same as `\bigskip`).

[image]

[image]

The other lengths that were mentioned are "softer" and allow for some stretch/shrink.

For consistency, you can also increase the skip between paragraphs (known as `\parskip`) under Document > Settings... > Text Layout > Separate paragraphs with > Vertical space:

[image]

Comment: When shoul I use \newline instead?

Comment: That `\vspace{}` seems really useful. :-ThumbUp

Comment: How about using `\newline` as @skan asked?

Answer (score 41):

You can use *bigbreak*:

```
alfa bravo
\bigbreak
charlie delta
```

**Background** (from @egreg [answer in a more general question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/76755))

`\bigbreak` isn't listed in the LaTeX manual. It removes a preceding vertical space if it's less than what it would insert; it also terminates a paragraph and tells TeX that it marks a good point where a page break may happen.

Comment: note `\bigbreak` encourages a pagebreak. Just good to know when it's undesired. `\bigskip` would be similar but without the potential pagebreak effect.

Answer (score 21):

If you want a finer control over your layout you can use \vskip.

```
Some text
\vskip 0.2in
Some text
```

You can change the value and units should you desire.

Anothing thing you can do is create a custom command:

```
\newcommand{\newpara}
    {
    \vskip 1cm
    }
```

So now you can just type \newpara in much the same way as \newline:

```
Some text
\newpara
Some text
```

Not sure how this functions in LyX but since it uses the LaTeX language it should work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I like this flexibility,...which made me try `\hskip 0.2in` and that worked just as well, FYI. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

No need to use extra code other than double backslash. After ending a paragraph, give `\\` and put an empty line there. Combinedly it will work for putting an extra blank line.

Like:

```
I am a LaTeX user.\\

I am a LaTeX user.
```

Check this. It will give an extra empty line between the two lines.

And if you want to use any other size of spacing, you can use `\\[]`. For example: `\\[2in]`

This will put an extra 2-inch space between the two lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid this isn't a good way of doing things.  You should never end a paragraph with ```\\```, see e.g. [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495) and [When to use \par and when \\ ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer

But as I faced, putting only a blank space doesn't help in putting an extra blank line between the paragraph. Even using \par does not either. So what should be used for putting a blank line between two paragraph, without front indent?

Comment: For LyX, see the above answer. For LaTeX, add `\usepackage{parskip}` to the preamble.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the thing I was wondering. After adding the package, the command is working now.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am new to LaTeX but I think one of its main problem is the lack of a true command for paragraphs spacind.`\parskip` does awfull things to section spacing, and table of contents !!

Comment: @JohnMarjan Ehm, OK. I've never had that problem, as I hardly ever have the need to change the parskip. And I'm just a user, so complaining to *me* is sort of pointless to be honest. (Also, I didn't say anything about modifying `\parskip` (with `\setlength`), I said add `\usepackage{parskip}`.That doesn't modify the ToC at least. Note that some document classes (KOMA classes and `memoir` at least, I think) have their own interfaces for this sort of thing.)

Comment: I am just a user to. I don't see the harm in raising the problem, up to you or another. I just meant that when you redefine the `parskip` it changes your TOC