# How to remove space after the description label and add after the whole description?

Tags: spacing, lists, description

I have the following tex source:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem 
ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum 
dolorLorem ipsum dolor

\begin{description}
\item[Google LG Nexus 4] \hfill \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Release date: November 2012,
\item CPU: Qualcomm Snapdragon\texttrademark~S4 Pro processor (ARMv7, 1.5GHz quad core),
\item GPU: Ardeno 320.
\end{itemize}
\item[Samsung Galaxy S III] \hfill \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Release date: May 2012,
\item CPU: Exynos 4 Quad 4412 (ARMv7, 1.4GHz quad core),
\item GPU: ARM Mali-400MP.
\end{itemize}
```

which produces the following pdf:

[image]

I need to remove the spacing after the description labels (Google LG Nexus 4 and Samsung Galaxy S III) and add it after the nested list).

I tried with `enumitem` and `\setlist{nolistsep}` but that just made the nested list more compact:

How can I do this?

Comment: the extra space is being added by the double backslash after the "labels".  if you need to have something for item text, try `\leavevmode`.  (this is recommended for quite a few other questions, but i haven't found a good one to point to.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't even need to use `\leavevmode`. It was enough to get rid of those `\\` and now I have what I wanted:) You can post it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the extra space -- in fact, a whole new line -- is being added by the double backslashes
following the item that forms the label for a group.

the need for a double backslash to end a line is rare outside of a tabular or
multi-line math display mode.  the general principles are presented in the answers
to these questions:

- [Best choice between using `\\` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495)
- [When to use \par and when `\\`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the `itemize` to start on a new line, just issue `\mbox{}` and not `\hfill\\`. To reduce the vertical spacing around the `itemize`, set `\topsep` to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem
ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum
dolorLorem ipsum dolor

\begin{description}
\item[Google LG Nexus 4] \mbox{}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item Release date: November 2012,
\item CPU: Qualcomm Snapdragon\texttrademark~S4 Pro processor (ARMv7, 1.5GHz quad core),
\item GPU: Ardeno 320.
\end{itemize}
\item[Samsung Galaxy S III] \mbox{}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item Release date: May 2012,
\item CPU: Exynos 4 Quad 4412 (ARMv7, 1.4GHz quad core),
\item GPU: ARM Mali-400MP.
\end{itemize}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want an alternative input for this kind of descriptions; this ensures no page break will take place after the boldface label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{describephone}[1]
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\par\nobreak\vspace{1ex}%
  \@afterheading
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]}
 {\end{itemize}\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem 
ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum 
dolorLorem ipsum dolor

\begin{describephone}{Google LG Nexus 4}
\item Release date: November 2012,
\item CPU: Qualcomm Snapdragon\texttrademark~S4 Pro processor (ARMv7, 1.5GHz quad core),
\item GPU: Ardeno 320.
\end{describephone}

\begin{describephone}{Samsung Galaxy S III}
\item Release date: May 2012,
\item CPU: Exynos 4 Quad 4412 (ARMv7, 1.4GHz quad core),
\item GPU: ARM Mali-400MP.
\end{describephone}

Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem 
ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum 
dolorLorem ipsum dolor

\end{document}
```

[image]