# Blank space between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, texmaker, line-spacing

I am trying to learn how to use Texmaker (just for the record, I don't know a single thing about programming or Latex) and I am having some difficulty to create space between paragraphs or between lines. For example, I start my document with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Semisimple modules

Theorem...

\end{document}
```

I want to leave an empty line between "Semisimple modules" and "Theorem...", how can I do this?

Remember that I am a completely newbie with Texmaker (and with programs in general...) so please be patient with me if I ask too obvious things or if I make silly mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Are you looking for package `parskip`?

Comment: Little advice: One ouf our members wrote a good [introduction for novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/). You can check it out if you want to.

Comment: `Semisimple modules \\ [blankline] 

Theorem...`

would do the trick, if you  only  want to insert a blank line.

Comment: Meta-comment: You're trying to learn LaTeX here, not Texmaker. There are [a lot of text editors that have LaTeX specific features](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), and whether you write that code in Texmaker or any of the others is mostly completely irrelevant - it is the code itself that matters, not which program you've written it in, the output will be the same.

Comment: @Bernard -- please, no double backslashes to leave blank lines!  see [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495/579)

Comment: @barbara beeton: I know that but the O.P. specifically asked for a `blank`  space between paragraphs — and I understood it as ‘between two particular paragraphs’, so I couldn't simply say `\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}`, which would be global. Unless I misunderstood thz O.P.'s requirement?

Comment: @Bernard -- since s/he is presumably trying to learn, it's not a good idea to start off by teaching bad practices that have to be unlearned later.  recommending a good introduction (as already done in a comment) is really more helpful even than a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to give structure to your document. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Semisimple modules}

A module is said to be \emph{semisimple} if it equals the sum
of its simple submodules. Note that the zero module is semisimple,
being the sum of the (empty) family of its simple submodules.

A ring is called \emph{semisimple} if it is semisimple as a right
module over itself. We shall see later that right semisimple is
the same as left semisimple, so we can omit the indication of the
side.

\begin{thm}
A module is semisimple if and only if it is a direct sum of
simple submodules.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
It's obvious, isn't it?
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the space above and below the statement is automatically added.