# How to indent all my paragraph in a single command?

Tags: indentation

I have a rather big document, my thesis actually, and I would like to indent all of my paragraphs. Of course, I could use the command `\indent` in every single paragraph, but that's extremely cumbersome.

So, how can I tell LaTeX, with a single command, to indent not only the first paragraph of a section, but all of them.

I'm using Texmaker, by the way.

Comment: Just end a paragraph by leaving a blank line in the TeX file. If you use ``\\``, it's the wrong way.

Comment: And if you need paragraphs indented even after section headings as well and you are using any of the standard document classes, load the `indentfirst` package.

Comment: Going line by line putting a blank space in between is the same as just putting an "\indet".
If it can be easily done in Word it should be possible to get it done with a single line in latex...

Comment: You need some way to mark a paragraph in the source as opposed to just a word space. In tex that is a blank line, it could not be much less markup??

Comment: Word marks a paragraph with a hidden mark that you don't see, but it's there.  LaTeX just uses a blank line instead of a hidden mark.  What's the difference? The real issue is that when you entered your source document you didn't mark the paragraphs correctly, and now you want LaTeX to solve that problem for you, but it can't.

Comment: @Est: Putting a blank space is faster than typing `\indent`: only `two carriage returns`. Otherwise, you can type `par` at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: Well there's the “\\” obviously and that should be enough. It prolly is, I’m just unable to get it done.

Comment: No as @egreg already told you, \\  does *not* end a paragraph. You need to replace all those with blank lines in the places you need new paragraphs.  (Since \\ has legitimate uses other places, I would not recommend doing a global search and replace.)

Comment: @Est have you seen _any_ documentation that suggests `\\ ` ends a paragraph? If there is any we should get it fixed.

Comment: For an explanation see [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495/2693)

Comment: yeap, u guys seem to be rather right. THX for correcting me in my mistake. Bad on me. I’m adding the blank lines as I… write haha

Answer (score 7):

You never need to use `\indent` at the start of a paragraph (it does nothing there at all, it is just in the language for symmetry with `\noindent`.

The indentation can be controlled for all paragraphs by setting `\parindent`

[image]

Note how the second two paragraphs using `\indent` match the first two.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{5cm}
%\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.

One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.


\indent One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.

\indent One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.

\end{document}
```

uncomment the line to set `\parindent` to zero and you get
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to get LaTeX to solve a problem of your own making. The correct way to mark a new paragraph in LaTeX is to leave a blank line between it and the previous paragraph. Instead of doing this, you have probably used `\\`, which is incorrect, since it does not start a new paragraph, but merely forces the text onto the next line.  See

- [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495/2693)

If you correctly use blank lines to separate paragraphs, then every paragraph except those that appear immediately after a section heading will be indented automatically.  If for some reason you need to indent those paragraphs also, you can load the `indentfirst` package, which will cause all paragraphs even those following a section heading to be indented.

Since there are various places in which the use of `\\` is valid (inside tabulars, for example, but also other places) I would not recommend doing a global search and replace of all such instances in your file.