# What is the difference between \\ and skipping a line?

Tags: paragraphs

What different effects do ending a paragraph in the following three ways have?

1.

```
    words words words

    words words words
```

2.

```
    words words words\\
    words words words
```

3.

```
    words words words\\

    words words words
```

Comment: The first is good, the second is bad, the third is wrong.

Comment: The first provides a paragraph break, the second is a forced line break within a paragraph, which is not generally recommended.  Since many LaTeX actions are only executed at the end of a paragraph, the seeming small difference in syntax can have a profound appearance on the output.

Comment: @egreg The good, the bad, and the ugly.

Comment: this is relevant: [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495/579).  also, it's not *always* bad to use `\\ ` in the middle of a paragraph, if you really want to start a new line leaving the current line short; this can be useful in formatting instructive examples in a manual, but should be used consciously, sparingly and wisely.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment,  "The first provides a paragraph break, the second is a forced line break within a paragraph, which is not generally recommended. Since many LaTeX actions are only executed at the end of a paragraph, the seeming small difference in syntax can have a profound appearance on the output."

Here are some examples of functional differences.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}

CENTERING:

{
line 1

line 2\centering

}

\noindent versus

{
line 1\\
line 2\centering

}

\noindent\hrulefill

PARAGRAPH SPACING AND INDENTS

{\parskip 1em
line 1

line 2

}

\noindent versus

{\parskip 1em
line 1\\
line 2

}

\noindent\hrulefill

LEFT AND RIGHT SKIPS

{
line 1

line 2\leftskip 1in

}

\noindent versus

{
line 1\\
line 2\leftskip 1in

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note this code can be automated in a macro  (note that an extra blank line is the same thing as a `\par` for the purposes of LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand\stencil[3]{\par\bgroup#2 line 1#1line 2#3\par\egroup}
\begin{document}
CENTERING:

\stencil{\par}{}{\centering}
\noindent versus
\stencil{\\}{}{\centering}
\noindent\hrulefill

PARAGRAPH SPACING AND INDENTS

\stencil{\par}{\parskip 1em}{}
\noindent versus
\stencil{\\}{\parskip 1em}{}

\noindent\hrulefill

LEFT AND RIGHT SKIPS

\stencil{\par}{}{\leftskip 1in}
\noindent versus
\stencil{\\}{}{\leftskip 1in}
\end{document}
```