# Underfull hbox error using \newline and \hfill\break

Tags: line-breaking

I am trying to remove warnings/errors from the document I am writing that includes underfull (and overfull) `\hbox`s from the code below. Why does `\newline` and `\hfill\break` produce this warning? Aren't these commands supposed to fill lines and remove this error?

I am new to LaTeX (and this forum), I have been searching through several (already asked) questions, and guides (including 'The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX' (Oetiker 2015), and 'LaTeX' (en.wikibooks.org)), all of which say that this is supposed to remove this error, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I am using TeXstudio 2.10.8, and MiKTeX 2.9 if it makes any difference.

This is the code I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, onecolumn]{book}

\begin{document}
\noindent \emph{I want this text to act as a heading} \newline
\newline
By having it separated by a line \newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `\newline`. Just leave an empty line!

Comment: Welcome, i suspect you want a paragraph break there with some vertical space, correct? If so, use something like `\medbreak`. Depending on what you want to do, setting up an extra sectioning comand might be a much better idea.

Comment: If you find yourself using `\newline` or `\\ ` in a document then something is wrong, certainly never use two consecutive ones or use such a command at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: @Johannes_B good suggestion. But ChristianHupfer, and DavidCarlisle if I shouldn't use \newline, when should it be used, and why does it produce an Underfull \hbox?

Comment: Using  `\newline` is a very common thing starters understand wrong. [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495) and [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `\newline` then the error will go. In comments you ask why adding a `\newline` at the end of the paragraph produces a warning.

```
\emph{I want this text to act as a heading} \newline
```

forces a line break right at the end of the paragraph this produces a spurious empty line following this forced break with no content so it is *very* under full and produces the maximum badness of 10000.