# Varying spacing after line break

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, line-spacing

```
Before line break

After line break
```

An empty line between two sentences usually gets me a line break without any additional spacing.
For some reason, on the second page of the same chapter, there is additional spacing after each line break and also more spacing after `\\`.

Why is that? Is TeX somehow trying to fill the page before the following section? I'd like to constantly have no extra spacing after line breaks and `\\`.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example? There may be several reasons for this. Just in case: what happens if you add the `raggedbottom` directive to your preamble?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the effect in a small example, but the effect disappears with `raggedbottom` and all the line breaks appear without extra spacing. What does it do exactly?

Comment: By default LaTeX tries to have all pages have the same physical height (\textheight) and to this effect, plays with so called  ‘rubber lengths’. Sometimes this is not enough and you obtain a lot of unwanted white spaces on pages. This is the optiion `\flushbottom`. With `\raggedbottom`, the bottom of pages are allowed not to be exactly at the same height on the physical page.

Comment: regarding the use of a double backslash instead of a blank line for the end of a paragraph, see [Best choice between using ``\\`` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495).  you will *always* get extra space if you use a double backslash at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, I use \\ when I actually want extra space and not just a simple line break without space. This [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces#Line_breaks) suggests that \\ and `\newline` are equal.

Comment: `\\ ` does not add any space unless you use the argument form `\\[10pt]`  (Never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph that just generates a warning and an extra line of the paragraph, not vertical space)