# Why not use "\\"?

Tags: best-practices, text

This is *probably* a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find one.

I remember early on in my days of learning LaTeX that I was in the habit of using `\\` to end every line of text. These days, I don't - what I do is I add a blank line after the line of text, and then start a new line of text a few lines later. I.e., instead of

```
This is some text \\
This is some more text
```

I do

```
This is some text

This is some more text
```

I saw the use of `\\` in some code to end every line, and my instinct was that it was bad code.

Can someone (re)-explain to me why it is bad to use `\\` to end every line of text, preferably with examples to illustrate the points? Or did I just imagine that it is bad to use `\\` to end each line of text?

Comment: I think this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/ and this one explains it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/

Comment: In short: Add `\setlength{\parskip}{6em}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}` to the preamble and you will see the difference between line breaks and paragraph breaks.