# List of deprecated commands and their `appreciated' alternatives

Tags: macros, incompatibility, robust-commands

I'm wondering if there is a list of deprecated LaTeX commands and suggestions for commands that are to be used instead.

Comment: not really, there are no commands in the latex format officially classed as deprecated, and if you include contributed packages, there are thousands of packages, some of which may or may not be classed as replacements or improvements on other packages, depending who you ask.

Comment: You can find suggestions under the [`best-practices`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) tag, such as [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa) or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-make).

Comment: Related: [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: Run `texdoc l2tabuen` in the OS prompt.

Long answer: Although may be are not officially deprecated LaTeX2e commands, as David said, novices often fall in old documentation, examples and templates, taking obsolete or not well understood practices, as writing the non-deprecated `\'{a}` when with minimal settings in the preamble and a suitable keyboard you can simply write "`á`", or using the deprecated  `{\bf ... }` of LaTeX2.0, that do not use the new font selection scheme (NFSS) of LaTeX2e, instead of `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}`, or using obsolete packages (as `anysize` to set up document margins instead of the `ge­om­e­try` pack­age) and even obsolete fonts and classes.

One should mention also  `inputenc`, in no way an obsolete package, but since utf8 is actually the gold standard encoding, use of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with pdflatex is obsolete at least in standard classes because is now the default, but the novice will see this command in thousands of examples anywhere. It will take time to forget it!

Others, not so novices tend to use TeX commands instead of the LaTeX syntax (often my fault), as `\parindent1em` instead of  `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}` or  `\def\foo{...}`  instead of `\newcommand\foo{..}`. In my defense I will say that this is fine while you understand the risks.

Many of these common pitfalls are covered by the [l2tabu](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu) german document (note that there are an [English version](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)  as well as in some other languages).

Comment: On your note about `inputenc`: It's not actually deprecated, but since [April 2018](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf) the file `utf8.def` (loaded by `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) is included in LaTeX by default, so including `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in releases later than April 2018 will simply do nothing. And since this is in the LaTeX kernel, it affects _any_ document class, not only the standard ones :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did not say that is a deprecated package, just the contrary ("in no way an obsolete package"). With respect a non standard class, I just created the `xxx.cls` custom class that is `\LoadClass{article} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and therefore utf8 is no longer the default encoding of any document class.  `:)`

Comment: Ooh, yes, if the class forces an encoding, then it's another story :)

Comment: For what it’s worth, I still put ``inputenc` in my PDFTeX examples here, because people sometimes still use old software. I add a comment that it’s been the default since 2018.