# Difference between `\sl` and `\slshape`?

Tags: slanted

What's the difference between using `\sl` and `\slshape`? I don't see any in the pdf.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/35864 and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd. Check out `{\bfseries\sl goo}` vs `{\bfseries\slshape foo}`.

Comment: TeX syntax vs LaTeX syntax. LaTeX font commands are are commutative, TeXs are not (bf it is not the same as it bf in TeX)

Comment: Run `texdoc l2tabuen`. Then move to page 8.

Comment: Related: [List of deprecated commands and their `appreciated' alternatives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348453/list-of-deprecated-commands-and-their-appreciated-alternatives).