# Texmaker \color or \textcolor: no line to end error

Tags: errors, color

I'm new to LaTeX and I don't get where my error is. I'm running on Windows under Texmaker.
I only recieve this message : "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc,multido,ifthen,bm}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{Sujet 4}
\begin{document}
\section {Exercice 4 :} Soit $P(x) = x^3 - x + 1 $.
\\
txt
\\
\textcolor{blue} {On sait que $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\overline{\beta}$ sont les 3 racines du polynômes P. Donc P peut s'ecrire sous forme scindée : 
$$P(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\overline{\beta})$$
$P(x)=(x^2-\beta x-\alpha x+\alpha \beta)(x-\overline{\beta})$ en développant
$$P(x)=x^3-\beta x^2 - \alpha x^2 +\alpha \beta x -\overline{\beta} x^2 +\beta \overline{\beta} x + \alpha \overline{\beta} x - \alpha \beta \overline{\beta}$$ 
Par identification, on obtient notamment :
\[-\alpha \beta \overline{\beta} = 1$$
$$\lvert \alpha \beta \overline{\beta} \rvert = 1$$
$$\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert \lvert \overline{\beta} \rvert = 1$$
$$\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert^2 = 1$$
$$\lvert \beta \rvert=\frac{1}{\lvert \alpha \rvert}\]
or $\alpha <-1$ donc $\lvert \alpha \rvert>1$
donc $\lvert \beta \rvert<1$}
\end{document}
```

There, I've done what you have said. I tried to run it but I had the same error in the same line.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: (i) in preamble remove all double loaded packages, (ii) instead of `$$ ... $$` use `\[ ... \]`, (iii) merge both code sniped into one (small) document that we can test it. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let me elaborate my comment (as supplement to [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) answer): `\textcolor{<color>}{.....}` doesn't work over more paragraphs (as is your case). instead you should rather use switch `\color{<color>}` and after end of colored part of document switch back with  `\color{black}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc,multido,ifthen,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{Sujet 4}

\begin{document}
\section {Exercice 4 :} Soit $P(x) = x^3 - x + 1 $.
\\
txt
\\
\color{blue}
On sait que $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\overline{\beta}$ sont les 3 racines du polynômes P. Donc P peut s'ecrire sous forme scindée :
    \[
P(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\overline{\beta})
    \]
$P(x)=(x^2-\beta x-\alpha x+\alpha \beta)(x-\overline{\beta})$ en développant
    \[
P(x)=x^3-\beta x^2 - \alpha x^2 +\alpha \beta x -\overline{\beta} x^2 +\beta \overline{\beta} x + \alpha \overline{\beta} x - \alpha \beta \overline{\beta}
    \]
Par identification, on obtient notamment :
    \begin{align*}
-\alpha \beta \overline{\beta}
    & = 1  \\
\lvert \alpha \beta \overline{\beta} \rvert
    & = 1\\
\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert \lvert \overline{\beta} \rvert
    & = 1\\
\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert^2
    & = 1\\
\lvert \beta \rvert
    & =\frac{1}{\lvert \alpha \rvert}
    \end{align*}
or $\alpha <-1$ donc $\lvert \alpha \rvert>1$
donc $\lvert \beta \rvert<1$

\color{black}
some text
\end{document}
```

by the way, Textmaker have nothing with your problem. it is only editor for `latex`.

Comment: Thank you Zarko ! What does " & = 1  \\" stand for ?

Comment: `&` is anchor to which equations are aligned.

Answer (score 5):

The error message you got was caused by the misuse of `\\` to denote linebreaks, leave an empty line instead, see [Best choice between using \\ or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa)

Some additional problems (some already mentioned in [Zarko's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396570/texmaker-color-or-textcolor-no-line-to-end-error/396572#comment986593_396570)):

- please don't load packages multiple times
- if you load `xcolor` you don't need to load `color`
- same for `graphicx`, you don't need to load `graphics` then
- `$$ ... $$` should not be used, please use `\[...\]` instead, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)
- `natbib` has to be loaded before `babel` (there should have been a warning to tell you this)
- while `\textcolor{blue}{...}` works in this case, my personal preference would be to use `\color{blue}` for larger portions or the document and switch back to black afterwards (`\color{blue} .... \color{black}`). This is just my personal taste.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc,multido,ifthen,
%color,
bm}
%\usepackage{graphics} 
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{natbib}% before babel!
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{Sujet 4}
\begin{document}
\section {Exercice 4 :} 
Soit $P(x) = x^3 - x + 1 $.
%\\

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item   Montrer que P admet une unique racine reelle que l'on notera $\alpha$. Verifier que $\alpha < -1$.
    \item Montrer que P admet deux autres racines $\beta$ et $\gamma$ verifiant $\beta = \bar{\gamma}$.
    \item Montrer que $\vert \beta \vert < 1$.
    \item On pose pour tout $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $u_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + \gamma^n$. Calculer $u_0$, $u_1$, $u_2$.
    \item Montrer que $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,$ u_{n+3} - u_{n+1} + u_n = 0$.
    \item Montrer que $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,$ u_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
    \item Determiner $\lim_{n \to +\infty} = \vert \alpha\vert^n$.
    \item Determiner (si elle existe) $\lim_{n \to +\infty} = \sin( \pi\alpha^n)$.
\end{enumerate}
%\\

\color{blue} On sait que $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\overline{\beta}$ sont les 3 racines du polynomes P. Donc P peut s'ecrire sous forme scindee : 
\[P(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\overline{\beta})\]
$P(x)=(x^2-\beta x-\alpha x+\alpha \beta)(x-\overline{\beta})$ en développant
\[P(x)=x^3-\beta x^2 - \alpha x^2 +\alpha \beta x -\overline{\beta} x^2 +\beta \overline{\beta} x + \alpha \overline{\beta} x - \alpha \beta \overline{\beta}\]
Par identification, on obtient notamment :
\[-\alpha \beta \overline{\beta} = 1\]
\[\lvert \alpha \beta \overline{\beta} \rvert = 1\]
\[\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert \lvert \overline{\beta} \rvert = 1\]
\[\lvert \alpha \rvert \lvert \beta \rvert^2 = 1\]
\[\lvert \beta \rvert=\frac{1}{\lvert \alpha \rvert}\]
or $\alpha <-1$ donc $\lvert \alpha \rvert>1$
donc $\lvert \beta \rvert<1$
\color{black}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you !! Just, why do we need to put "\usepackage{natbib}" before babel ?

Comment: @Sin Because the package tells you to do so :)

Comment: Fair enought =P Thank you very much. I'll be more careful nest time =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to switch the color back if you enclose the whole expression in two curly brackets:

```
{{\color{blue} blue text }}
```

will print "blue text" in blue, then pop back to the original color.