# APA6 Class: Manual line-break using "\\" or better solution?

Tags: line-breaking, apa6

I am writing my master thesis using the APA6 class (see MWE below). I am not a Latex expert and have used `\\` as a manual line-break from the beginning. Now I read in a comment to a different topic that you shouldn't use `\\`. Could you explain this and suggest a better solution for line-breaks in my thesis?

MWE:

```
        \documentclass{apa6}
    \begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\\
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa

Comment: Just let the text flow. If you want a new paragraph, use a blank line instead of ``\\``.

Comment: why do you want to force a linebreak at all? just delete the `\\ `

Comment: I didn't even know that I can start a new paragraph by using a blank line ;-) Thank you!