# Getting "Theres no line here to end" - exception

Tags: errors, line-breaking

I am writing my thesis and have gone to the next line by the `~\\`-command and sometimes (when I wanted to hop over one line) by the `~\\\newline`-commands.

And this has worked all the time until now, where I get  many exceptions caused by all those `~\\ \newline`-commands (Which had worked all the time before):

[image]

Does anybody of you know why I get that exception from one moment to another?

Comment: don't use \\ for new lines.

Comment: But why has it worked all the time?

Comment: If you want a blank line between paragraphs use package parskip.

Comment: It should have never worked. The input is just plain wrong.

Comment: @watchme please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa

Comment: Does it make a difference when I use "~\\\newline" or "~\\ 
\newline" (\newline in the next line)?

Comment: Do not use double backslash *nor* \newline in normal text.

Comment: Yes but I want to find out why it has worked but doesn't now.

Comment: I get that I shouldn't use it now, but still I want to know it, because it is a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

You should never need `\\` or `\newline` to end a line and certainly never `~\\`..

You have not provided a usable  example  so need to make some guesses to answer.

The form you show with `\newline` after `\\` would normally not be an error but would make the warning

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 28--29
```

note that badness of 10000 is *infinitely bad* according to TeX's measure of how bad the document is.

However in the scope of some commands such as `\raggedright` the definition of `\\` changes and it goes from being just infinitely bad to being an error.

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

---

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}


zzzz.\\\newline


\raggedright

zzzz.\\\newline
\end{document}
```

This produces two warnings from the first use and an error from the second:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--8


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--8


! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 zzzz.\\\newline

?
```