# Why \\[12pt] followed by an empty line adds more space

Tags: spacing

To add vertical space between paragraphs we can use \vspace{12pt} or \\[12pt]. But why does the latter adds more space when it is followed by an empty line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
My first para.\vspace{12pt}

My second para.\\[12pt]

My third para.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ending a paragraph with `\\ ` is absolutely wrong.  See [Best choice between using ``\\`` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495).  And you should leave a blank line before `\vspace`.

Comment: According to sourc2e (CTAN) `\\[...]` is defined as `\vspace{...}\newline`, and `\newline\par` adds an extra line..

Comment: the first example is ok but it is much better to leave a blank line before the vspace. the second example is wrong it is a two line paragraph with an empty second line. latex gives the maximum badness warning that the output here is bad.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249?r=SearchResults#334249