# Why does the second paragraph not indent?

Tags: paragraphs

Does anyone know why the second paragraph is not indenting correctly?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please don't post screen shots of code, but copy and paste it.  That way, we can copy and paste to see what you're seeing (it also makes it possible for web searchers to see your question).  But as likethevegetable observes, you're instructing TeX that you want a new line, not a new paragraph.

Comment: you only have one paragraph in the text shown

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Best choice between using ``\\`` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495)

Comment: Suggestion: if you're going to use LaTeX, going through [learnlatex.org](https://www.learnlatex.org/) lessons will pay off greatly. Your question is covered in the [third less](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-03)

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you end a paragraph. `\\` ends the line. See this for more help: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraphs_and_new_lines

```
Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2.

or 

Paragraph 1.\par
Paragraph 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

So `\\` is not used to start a paragraph with indentation. It is simply newline character.
[image]

Just enter an empty line to start a paragraph with an indentation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also have the options to use `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip`. Do not forget to add a free line after them.

Comment: I do not recommend these for in-between paragraphs

Comment: Me neither, but the question was also a bit unclear. Just wanted to give a further option which was not mentioned yet.