# Issues with subsections alignment

Tags: sectioning, alignment

I was checking the notes from my physics class and I noticed that section 1.2 and the subsection 1.2.1 aren't aligned correctly... What's the issue?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5in,bottom=2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{
  amsmath,
  amssymb,
  amsthm,
  booktabs,
  color,
  mathrsfs,
  psfrag,
  pgfplots,
  physics,
  tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}

\title{Appunti di Fisica 2}
\author{Abcd}

\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Elettromagnetismo}
\section{La forza di Coulomb}
\noindent La forza di Coulomb è la forza che attrae o respinge due cariche elettriche puntiformi
$$ \vb{F_1}=\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \frac{\vb{r_1}-\vb{r_2}}{\left| \vb{r_1}-\vb{r_2}\right|^{3}} $$
\begin{enumerate}
  \item La forza esercitata dalla seconda carica è $\vb{F_2} = -\vb{F_1}$
  \item $\epsilon_0$ la costante dielettrica del vuoto e vale $8.85 \cdot 10^{-12}\, Fm^{-1}$ 
  \item Il protone ha carica pari a $1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}\, C$   
  \item L'elettrone ha carica pari a $-1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}\, C$
\end{enumerate}
\noindent Ci sono tre tipi di densità di carica elettrica:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{Lineare:} 
  E' la quantità di carica per unità di lunghezza.
  $$ \lambda(\vb{r'})=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}l'} $$
  \item \textbf{Superficiale:}
  E' la quantità di carica per unità di superficie.
  $$ \sigma(\vb{r'})=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}S'} $$
  \item \textbf{Volumetrica:}
  E' la quantità di carica per unità di volume. 
  $$ \rho(\vb{r'})=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}V'} $$
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\quad
\section{Il campo elettrico}
$$ \vb{E}(\vb{r})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^{N} Q_i \frac{\vb{r}-\vb{r_i}}{\left| \vb{r}-\vb{r_i} \right|^{3}} $$ 
\noindent Quando le cariche non sono finite (e quindi N tende all'infinito):
$$ \vb{E}(\vb{r})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_{}^{}\frac{\vb{r}-\vb{r'}}{\left|\vb{r}-\vb{r'} \right|^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}q' $$
\subsection{Campo elettrico di un filo rettilineo uniformemente carico}
\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=mygray] (-10cm,-0.2cm) rectangle (4cm,0.2cm);
  \draw[dashed] (-3cm,-1cm) -- (-3cm,4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=orange] (-1cm,-0.2cm) rectangle (-0.5cm,0.2cm) node[above right=5pt]{$dx$};
  \draw[dashed] (-0.75cm,0.2cm) -- (-3cm,4cm) node[midway, above right]{$r$};
  \filldraw (-3cm,4cm) circle[radius=2pt] node[above right]{$P$};
  \draw (-10cm,0.2cm) -- (4cm,0.2cm) node[left,above left]{$L$};
  \draw (-3cm,-0.2cm) -- (-1.5cm,-0.2cm) node[midway,below=5pt]{$x$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (-3cm,4cm) -- (-3.9cm,6cm) node[above left]{$dE$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (-3cm,4cm) -- (-3cm,6cm) node[above right]{$dE_y$};
  \draw (-3cm,0) coordinate (a)
        (-3cm,4cm) coordinate (b)
        (-0.75cm,0.2cm) coordinate (c)
        pic["$\theta$",draw=orange,angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1.25cm]{angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture} \end{center}
$$ E=E_y=\int_{C}^{}\frac{\mathrm{d}q \cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\frac{\lambda y \mathrm{d}x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{Q}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y (L^2+4y^2)^{1/2}} $$
\noindent Se il filo è infinito:
$$ E=\lim_{L\to \infty} \frac{Q}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y (L^2+4y^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y} $$
\subsection{Campo elettrico di un anello uniformemente carico}
\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (a)
  (200pt,-50pt) coordinate (b)
  (0,100pt) coordinate (c) node[above left]{dL}
  pic["$\theta$", draw=orange, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=2cm]
  {angle=c--b--a};
  \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=70pt, y radius=100pt];
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,100pt) node[midway, left]{$R$};
  \draw[thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (200pt,-50pt) node[midway, above=12pt, left]{$x$};
  \draw[thick, dashed, red] (200pt,-50pt) -- (0,100pt) node[midway, above=5pt]{$r$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (200pt,-50pt) -- (300pt,-75pt) node[above right]{$\vec{dE_x}$};
  \filldraw[thick] (200pt,-50pt) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right]{$P$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (200pt,-50pt) -- (270pt,-95pt) node[above right]{$dE$};
\end{tikzpicture} \end{center}
$$ E=E_x = \int_{C}^{} \frac{\mathrm{d}q \cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} = \int_{0}^{2 \pi R} \frac{\lambda x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}L = \frac{Qx}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+R^2)^{3/2}} $$ 
\\[0.5cm]
\subsection{Campo elettrico di un disco uniformemente carico}
\noindent Il campo elettrico generato da un disco uniformemente carico è pari a quello generato da tutti gli anelli infinitesimali che lo compongono. Quindi
$$ \mathrm{d}E_x=\frac{x \mathrm{d}q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+r^2)^{3/2}} \to E_x=\int_{0}^{R} \frac{\sigma x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+r^2)^{3/2}}2 \pi R\,\mathrm{d}r=\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}\left[1-\frac{x}{(x^2+R^2)^{1/2}}\right] $$
Dove $r$ e $\mathrm{d}r$ sono rispettivamente il raggio e lo spessore di ogni anello infinitesimale. Se il disco è infinito:
$$ E=\lim_{R\to \infty} \frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} \left[1-\frac{x}{(x^2+R^2)^{1/2}}\right]=\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} $$
\end{document}
```

Update: going on I found out it does that on every even page. Moreover, it isn't because of the center environment: I tried to remove it and they're still misaligned.

** It was the `\documentclass{book}`... I solved by changing it to `\documentclass{report}`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Not tested:  I believe `\subsection` in `book` is run-in, so the `\center` following the heading will ultimately affect the heading as well.  Add something "harmless" (like `$ $`) following the heading and then a blank line to get out of horizontal mode.  Unrelated: it's recommended to use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$` with LaTeX.  Finally, instead of using `\\[<dimen>]` after a display, enter a blank line, then `\vspace{<dimen>}`.  The double backslash there will probably result in a confusing error message.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for all the useful notes about the notation. I'll keep them in mind. However, it still doesn't seem to work. I added `$  $ \\ `  and a blank line of code after both `\section{1.2}` and `\subsection{1.2.1}` but they aren't aligned yet. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You don't want that `\\ ` to end a paragraph; a blank line is enough.  (See [Best choice between using ``\\`` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495).)  I'll try to test this when I'm able; without seeing the output, I can't picture the actual alignment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's understandable.

Comment: Okay, I'm testing.  I get an error that I can't get past: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \theta
l.71 ...ngle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1.25cm]
                                                  {angle=a--b--c};
I tried setting this `tikzpicture` by itself, and got the same error, so there's some problem there that I can't figure out.  Removing the `tikzpicture`s and replacing them with `\begin{center}dummy text \end{center}` resulted in aligned headings.  So I conclude the problem is in the `tikz` code, which I'm not successfully debugging.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks a lot. You've been extremely helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was never the tikzpicture, It was the `\documentclass{book}`. I changed it to `\documentclass{report}` and everything works fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are *perfectly aligned* against the left margin.

The class `book` uses `twoside` as default option, so the left and right margins are different and positioned symmetrically on even and odd pages.

You can make the margins equal to each other by using the `oneside` option.

#### Standard output

[image]

#### With `oneside`

[image]

#### Improvements

Your code needs several improvements. You should use `\lvert` and `\rvert`, not `\left|` and `\right|`. Also, the subscripts should go outside: look at the difference between `\vb{F_1}` and `\vb{F}_1`.

Never ever use `$$` in LaTeX. And `\noindent` is rarely (if ever) used in a document.

Do you really need `psfrag`? If you don't know what a package is for, omit loading it.

Don't forget to announce LaTeX you're writing in Italian.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5in,bottom=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{
  amsmath,
  amssymb,
  amsthm,
  booktabs,
  color,
  mathrsfs,
%  psfrag, % <--- really?
  pgfplots,
  physics,
  tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}

\title{Appunti di Fisica 2}
\author{Abcd}

\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Elettromagnetismo}

\section{La forza di Coulomb}
La forza di Coulomb è la forza che attrae o respinge due cariche elettriche puntiformi
\[
\vb{F}_1=
\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot
\frac{\vb{r}_1-\vb{r}_2}{\lvert \vb{r}_1-\vb{r}_2\rvert^{3}}
\]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item La forza esercitata dalla seconda carica è $\vb{F}_2 = -\vb{F}_1$
  \item $\epsilon_0$ la costante dielettrica del vuoto e vale $8.85 \cdot 10^{-12}\, Fm^{-1}$ 
  \item Il protone ha carica pari a $1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}\, C$   
  \item L'elettrone ha carica pari a $-1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}\, C$
\end{enumerate}
Ci sono tre tipi di densità di carica elettrica:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{Lineare:} 
  È la quantità di carica per unità di lunghezza.
  \[ \lambda(\vb{r}')=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}l'} \]
  \item \textbf{Superficiale:}
  È la quantità di carica per unità di superficie.
  \[ \sigma(\vb{r}')=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}S'} \]
  \item \textbf{Volumetrica:}
  È la quantità di carica per unità di volume. 
  \[ \rho(\vb{r}')=\frac{\mathrm{d}q'}{\mathrm{d}V'} \]
\end{itemize}

\clearpage

\section{Il campo elettrico}
\[
\vb{E}(\vb{r})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^{N} 
  Q_i \frac{\vb{r}-\vb{r_i}}{\lvert \vb{r}-\vb{r_i} \rvert^{3}}
\] 
Quando le cariche non sono finite (e quindi $N$ tende all'infinito):
\[
\vb{E}(\vb{r})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}
 \int_{}^{}\frac{\vb{r}-\vb{r}'}{\lvert\vb{r}-\vb{r}' \rvert^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}q'
\]

\subsection{Campo elettrico di un filo rettilineo uniformemente carico}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[fill=mygray] (-10cm,-0.2cm) rectangle (4cm,0.2cm);
  \draw[dashed] (-3cm,-1cm) -- (-3cm,4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=orange] (-1cm,-0.2cm) rectangle (-0.5cm,0.2cm) node[above right=5pt]{$dx$};
  \draw[dashed] (-0.75cm,0.2cm) -- (-3cm,4cm) node[midway, above right]{$r$};
  \filldraw (-3cm,4cm) circle[radius=2pt] node[above right]{$P$};
  \draw (-10cm,0.2cm) -- (4cm,0.2cm) node[left,above left]{$L$};
  \draw (-3cm,-0.2cm) -- (-1.5cm,-0.2cm) node[midway,below=5pt]{$x$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (-3cm,4cm) -- (-3.9cm,6cm) node[above left]{$dE$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (-3cm,4cm) -- (-3cm,6cm) node[above right]{$dE_y$};
  \draw (-3cm,0) coordinate (a)
        (-3cm,4cm) coordinate (b)
        (-0.75cm,0.2cm) coordinate (c)
        pic["$\theta$",draw=orange,angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1.25cm]{angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
E=E_y=\int_{C}^{}\frac{\mathrm{d}q \cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} = 
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\frac{\lambda y \mathrm{d}x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = 
\frac{Q}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y (L^2+4y^2)^{1/2}}
\end{gather*}
Se il filo è infinito:
\[
E=\lim_{L\to \infty} \frac{Q}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y (L^2+4y^2)^{1/2}} = 
\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 y}
\]

\subsection{Campo elettrico di un anello uniformemente carico}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (a)
  (200pt,-50pt) coordinate (b)
  (0,100pt) coordinate (c) node[above left]{dL}
  pic["$\theta$", draw=orange, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=2cm]
  {angle=c--b--a};
  \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=70pt, y radius=100pt];
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,100pt) node[midway, left]{$R$};
  \draw[thick, dashed] (0,0) -- (200pt,-50pt) node[midway, above=12pt, left]{$x$};
  \draw[thick, dashed, red] (200pt,-50pt) -- (0,100pt) node[midway, above=5pt]{$r$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (200pt,-50pt) -- (300pt,-75pt) node[above right]{$\vec{dE_x}$};
  \filldraw[thick] (200pt,-50pt) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right]{$P$};
  \draw[-{stealth[scale=2]}] (200pt,-50pt) -- (270pt,-95pt) node[above right]{$dE$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
 E=E_x = \int_{C}^{} \frac{\mathrm{d}q \cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} = 
\int_{0}^{2 \pi R} \frac{\lambda x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}L = 
\frac{Qx}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+R^2)^{3/2}}
\end{gather*} 

\subsection{Campo elettrico di un disco uniformemente carico}

Il campo elettrico generato da un disco uniformemente carico è pari a quello 
generato da tutti gli anelli infinitesimali che lo compongono. Quindi
\[
\mathrm{d}E_x=\frac{x \mathrm{d}q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+r^2)^{3/2}} \to E_x=
\int_{0}^{R} \frac{\sigma x}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (x^2+r^2)^{3/2}}2 \pi R\,\mathrm{d}r=
\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}\left[1-\frac{x}{(x^2+R^2)^{1/2}}\right]
\]
Dove $r$ e $\mathrm{d}r$ sono rispettivamente il raggio e lo spessore di ogni 
anello infinitesimale. Se il disco è infinito:
\[
E=\lim_{R\to \infty} \frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} \left[1-\frac{x}{(x^2+R^2)^{1/2}}\right]=
\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}
\]

\end{document}
```

Check the differences.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I changed my snippet for display math to use /[ /] already. Now I'll fix the other issues.