How to Make Title with Horizontal Lines Above and Below in Conference Paper Format
How would I go about formatting a document like the following?
I've tried to use the /rule command but I don't know if there's just a pre-made format that does this.
Thank you!

Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as \documentclass{}...\begin{document} etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

How to add lines to the title will depend on the code which produces the title, which in turn depends on the class or even what packages you use. Thus please add a small, but compilable test document.

Perhaps something like:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{ 
\rule[0.5ex]{1\textwidth}{1pt} \\
\sc Computational Life: How Well-Formed, Self-Replicating Programs Emerge from Simple Interaction\\
\rule[0.5ex]{1\textwidth}{1pt}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}




And please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa

Why load the geometry package?

The command \sc (along with \rm, \bf and similar ones) has been deprecated for 30 years.

Depending on the class and packages, this can mess up quite a lot in case the title is reused for pdf meta data or in a header/footer.

The geometry package is only there to imitate the picture the OP posted without the latex code. (Judging from the picture, his \textwidth is wider than the article class.) It will probably not be necessary in their setting, just like the \sc bit.
